# How to predict a single value with regression model?

Tags: python, statistics

I need to find expected brain mass for some picked body mass value.

```
Y = df_grouped_pow[['Brain mass (g)']]
X = sm.add_constant(a * np.power(Y, b))

model_pow = sm.OLS(Y, X)
result = model_pow.fit();
print(result.summary())
```

(a and b are previously calculated values. it doesn't really matters the question)
Here is a regression model and I wanted to make a prediction for a single value, but I don't know how to do it. It returns array of predicitions for the same given value and I understand why, but I wonder if I can make it return a single prediction for this single value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wanted to make a prediction for a single value

If you meant a prediction for a single input, simply use [Results.predict(exog=None, transform=True, *args, **kwargs)](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/dev/generated/statsmodels.base.model.Results.predict.html#statsmodels-base-model-results-predict), where `exog` is the input value array that matches the dimension of X. Note that `add_constant` will prepend a column of one to the data, so `x_predict` is also required to prepend a column of one, which can be added by `add_constant(data, has_constant='add')`.

```py
Y = df_grouped_pow[['Brain mass (g)']]
X = sm.add_constant(a * np.power(Y, b))

model_pow = sm.OLS(Y, X)
result = model_pow.fit();

X_predict = 3.0 # since your input X is one-dimension
X_predict = sm.add_constant([X_predict], has_constant='add') # The constant column also needs to be applied
print(result.predict(X_predict))
```

Comment: But the actual_X is a list of 3 values and I wanted to input one sorry if I don't understand something. i'm totally new with this. Moreover even when I copy this code I get an error:     ValueError: shapes (1,3) and (2,) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)

Comment: The `actual_X` is just an example. You should modify it based on your input shape.

Comment: For example, if the brain mass is predicted based on age and height, `[age, height]` is required for predicting the brain mass. You can't use only `age` to predict the result, at least not for OLS regression.

Comment: well yes if I put 2 values it works somewhat but I wonder why X = sm.add_constant(a * np.power(Y, b)) that's the function with one dependency, why does it need 2 values? (a, b are calculated already)

Comment: ah I see what you meant. Just noticed X is only based on Y.  I've edited the answer!

Comment: You saved me my guy thank you very much!

Comment: was glad to help!