# statsmodel predict issues with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

The issue is manipulating the X for the predicted input into such a way that it is of the same dimension. From what I can gather, I need to "pad" out the input to compensate for an added constant and that is why the dimensions do not match. Sadly I've not found a smart canonocial way to do that.

For example, my fitting code is the following:

```
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
```

predict is

```
X_pred = sm.add_constant(X_Pred)
r = model.predict(X_pred)
```

But I get a the following issue. X_pred is an out-of-training set example that is to be tested.

`ValueError: shapes (1,16) and (17,) not aligned: 16 (dim 1)` != 17 (dim 0)

Comment: see answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77609246/how-to-predict-a-single-value-with-regression-model/77609367#77609367   add_constant is a no-op by default if a column has constant values which is trivially satisfied if there is only one row.